# How to apply CSS to td of particular table?

Tags: html, css

How to apply CSS to td of one particular table; excluding all other tables in web page?

```
<table class="pure-table fullWidth" id="ToBeApplied">
 <tbody>
  <tr class="pure-table-odd">
   <td>
    <label>Bank</label>
   </td>
   <td>
    <label>Japha Bank</label>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<table class="pure-table fullWidth" id="NotToBeApplied">
 <tbody>
  <tr class="pure-table-odd">
   <td>
    <label>Bank</label>
   </td>
   <td>
    <label>Japha Bank</label>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to apply CSS say

```
td {padding:23px;font-weight:bold}
```

- i want to apply it on td's of table having ID ''ToBeApplied''.
- I do not want to write a class and write same on each td of table
- I do not want it to apply on td's of second table have ID ''NotToBeApplied''

How to modify HTML and CSS to achieve above?

Comment: `#ToBeApplied td{padding:23px;font-weight:bold}` for td that are in the `id='ToBeApplied'`

Comment: if you write `td { }` it will work for ALL td. Id you put `#ToBeApplied td` it will work for all td IN the table that gets `id=ToBeApplied`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/raog39pd/).

```
#ToBeApplied td {
    padding:23px;
    font-weight:bold
}
```

Here is the snippet.

```css
#ToBeApplied td {
  padding: 23px;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<table class="pure-table fullWidth" id="ToBeApplied">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="pure-table-odd">
      <td>
        <label>Bank</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>Japha Bank</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="pure-table fullWidth" id="NotToBeApplied">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="pure-table-odd">
      <td>
        <label>Bank</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>Japha Bank</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use CSS selectors like,

```css
#ToBeApplied td {
  padding:23px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work (Assuming that you dont want to specify `id` for table)

```
table.pure-table:first-child td {padding:23px;font-weight:bold}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/svunL6ve/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just add style below:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #ToBeApplied tr td{padding:23px;font-weight:bold}
</style>
```

One can limit the CSS application using the parent ahead of the style..

I hope this will help you achieve what you need!